# Delphi XE compiler fatal error after it mistakenly warns it had reached end of code

Tags: delphi

I have existing code that has worked for years that now throws a fatal error.  The errors stack up with the following error:

```
[DCC Error] fmMain.pas(1752): E2029 ')' expected but ',' found
[DCC Warning] fmMain.pas(1775): W1002 Symbol 'Point' is specific to a platform
[DCC Error] fmMain.pas(1775): E2029 ')' expected but ',' found
[DCC Error] fmMain.pas(1778): E2029 ';' expected but 'IF' found
[DCC Error] fmMain.pas(1779): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'fminiMove'
[DCC Error] fmMain.pas(1780): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'GISmMouseUp'
[DCC Error] fmMain.pas(1780): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Sender'
[DCC Error] fmMain.pas(1780): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Shift'
[DCC Error] fmMain.pas(1781): E2029 '.' expected but ';' found 
[DCC Warning] fmMain.pas(1782): W1011 Text after final 'END.' - ignored by compiler
```

The warning at line 1782 may be the key?  It is not the end of the code.  Line 1782 is actually "end;"

Comment: There's something wrong in your code just prior to line 1752

Comment: As well as not showing the code that fails, I'm surprised that you didn't tell us what you changed that lead to this problem.

Comment: Your first sentence implies that you haven't modified the code for years. Is that true? If not, then it hasn't "worked for years." Go back to the last working version of your code and check what changed. Delphi has built-in versioning that makes that task trivial.

Comment: I'm assuming you have at least one more `(` than you have `)`

Comment: As per David's comment: Even if the only thing you changed is compiler version, or upgraded a component... The fact is you changed ***something*** between your last successful compile and this failing one. And that's a **very important** piece of information to help solve your problem.

Comment: As your name would suggest, you should be inspecting the data more closely :) The compiler errors are usually very helpful in tracking what and where the problem is, and as others pointed out start from the first error message which is at Line 1752. It looks possibly like you added a comma at the end of a procedure and it expects one last closing bracket instead to finish of the procedure been called. If you posted some code of the error in question that would help everyone a great deal.

Answer (score 4):

It is usually the first error that points to the actual problem. The rest of the errors and warnings may well be because of the parser getting out of sync, due to the first error.
Check and double check the method at and around line 1752. Post it here if you can't see the error in your code.

Comment: Totally agree with this. You should always start fixing errors from top toward bottom becouse error on top can cause the compiler to treat all the code below in compleetly wrong way. This can result in compiler showing errors in code even thou that code itself is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on decription of the first error on line 1752 I gues you might be trying to pass more parameters than method is expecting.

Or if that is a declaration of method you forgot that method parameters must be delimited by semicolon and not comma.

Comment: Or just a simple `(` without a corresponding `)`

Comment: Error says that comma was found instead of closing bracket. Now if you would just forget the closing bracket itself the compiler would most likely say that semicolon was found instead of closing bracket since you put semicolon on the end of each line.